# Change Forward History using Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, browser-history, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to modify the Forward History of the browser. The requirement is I landed from Page-3 to Page-1, then If I click the forward button on browser, then I should be redirect to the Page-2.

I checked regarding History object and tried pushstate and replace history. But these change the Back button's history. Please suggest if this can be achieved with JS or shall resort to Back-end (Hybris/Java)

Comment: You can try to push 2 pages to history and then call `history.go(-1);`

Comment: Another solution would be implementing your own history and store it in the browser local storage(HTML5 only). After that you can handle the "onpopstate" event and do your logic there.